# How to pass an object from a view to another in laravel 5

Tags: parameter-passing, laravel-5

I already created some products, when I click one of them, I want to show more info for this product, how to do that in laravel 5?

Comment: Please leave out chit-chat ("thanks!") from your post, as per the help->tour.

Answer (score 0):

U need to use action show in ProductController and pass id

```
   public function show($id)
    {
        $product= Product::findOrFail($id);
        return View('product.show')->with('product',$product);
    }
```

now in view make link where u send your id of product

```
<a href="{{ action('ProductController@show', [$product->id]) }}">{{ $product->name}}</a>
```

then in your show view call atributes prom selected product

```
    <h3>{!! $product->name!!}</h3>
    <h3>{!! $product->price!!}</h3>
...
```